# Cannot create controller with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Getting the following error when trying to create a controller.

> There was an error running the selected code generator: "Unable to retrieve metadata for "ProjectName.Models.Tecnologia". One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ProjectName.DataContexts.Estadistica: EntityType "Estadistica" has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> Estadisticas: EntityType: EntitySet: "Estadisticas" is based on type "Estadistica" that has no key defined.

Class Tecnologia:

```
public class Tecnologia
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Usuario> TutoresCorrectores { get; set; }
    public List<FichaProyecto> FichasProyecto { get; set; }
}
```

Class Estadistica

```
public class Estadistica
{
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Porcentaje { get; set; }
}
```

Class DataContexts.GestionProyectodbContext

```
public class GestionProyectodbContext : DbContext
{
    public GestionProyectodbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Carrera> Carreras { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EstadoFicha> Estados { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FichaProyecto> FichasProyectos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grupo> Grupos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InformeAvance> InformesAvance { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InstanciaAcademica> InstanciasAcademicas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InstanciaEvaluacion> InstanciasEvaluacion { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PropuestaProyecto> PropuestasProyectos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reunion> Reuniones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rol> ListaRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tecnologia> Tecnologias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TipoAplicacion> TiposAplicaciones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TipoCliente> TiposClientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TipoProyecto> TiposProyectos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InformeTarea> InformesTareas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InformeCorreccion> InformesCorreccion { get; set; }
}
```

As seen, class "Estadistica" does not have an "ID" prop, but that's because I don't want to persist it in database. Id isn't even in the "GestionProyectodbContext" class, so it shouldn't be a problem. But when trying to create a controller por class "Tecnologia", an error saying that "Estadistica" has no key is popping. I don't know why this error is coming out, and I would some help from you if you somehow know why this happens.
PD: class "Tecnologia" is not even referring to class "Estadistica".
PD2: I know how to solve this error, but it's not the way I should be doing it, because I don't want to add an "ID" property into a class that I don't want to persist in the database.

Comment: try putting the data annotation `[Key]` over  `Cantidad`

Comment: you must have a mapped entity referencing this class... add NotMappedAttribute to it.

Comment: are you trying to create a controller using EF or are you just creating a controller for the read/write actions or an empty controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have an mapped entity referencing `Estadistica` apply the NotMapped attribute to it.

you can also use the fluent api to ignore it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Ignore<Estadistica>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EF only works when it knows the primary key of the table, By default it recognizes the primary key with name `Id`, but if you don't have `Id` column name in your table then decorate its primary key with `[Key]` attribute.

```
public class Estadistica
{
    [Key]
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Porcentaje { get; set; }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: might want to add the using statement along with the corresponding namespace that allows the use of data annotations in your answer, since the OP doesn't seem to be using data annotations in any of their classes.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to persist that table on my database, and I'm not even trying to create a controller for that class

Comment: FichaProyecto or Usuario, do any of these entities use Estadistica entity?!